# Only resolve DNS on VPN Server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, dns

I installed pptpd but my connection is too slow and i need use Google DNSes (8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4) on my Android without root for mobile network (not Wi-Fi). How can i configure my ubuntu server for just resolve dns on vpn?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

try on your dns vpn box to block all ports in iptables. keep port 53 (DNS) open and the port used to connect to the vpnc open as well.